# Symbolic Singular Value Decomposition? U,S,V as function of the elements of M

Tags: matrix, svd, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we want to compute the SVD of $\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
    m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
    m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
    m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$ (I picked size 3 for the sake of simplicity).

Is it possible to find expressions for $\mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{S}$, and $\mathbf{V}$ as function of the (symbolic) elements of $\mathbf{M}$, i.e, $\mathbf{U}(m_{i,j})$, $\mathbf{S}(m_{i,j})$, and $\mathbf{V}(m_{i,j})$? What the expressions look like?

Note: I know Matlab's svd function allows us to compute the singular values of the input matrix as function of symbolic variables, but to compute the singular vectors the input matrix should be numeric. Is there any mathematical software out there that would provide symbolic expressions $\mathbf{U}(m_{i,j})$, $\mathbf{S}(m_{i,j})$, and $\mathbf{V}(m_{i,j})$?

Comment: *Maybe* this would be of interest at [math.se].